# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\, \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\, \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\,\,\,$ converges in both interior and exterior of the the unit circle and represents an analytic function in each region.

I want to apply the Weierstrass M Test:I get if $|z|<r$ then $|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\,\,\,\,|<\frac{r^n}{1-r^n}\,\,\,$and now I couldn't continue from this point. Thanks for any help

Comment: When $|z| \leq r < 1$, everything is clear by your inequality plus Weierstrass $M$-test. For outside of the circle, notice that $$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}} = \frac{z^{-n}}{1+z^{-2n}} $$ so that you can use the result for $|z|<1$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: Why is it clear when $|z|  \leq r<1$? Thanks

Comment: Your inequality tells that $$ \left| \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}} \right| \leq \frac{r^n}{1-r^{2n}} \leq \frac{r^n}{1-r^2} $$ if $|z|\leq r < 1$. Can you apply the Weierstrass $M$-test now?

Comment: Yes, that helps, thanks.

Comment: You can also show that the series is invariant under the transformation $z\mapsto 1/z$.  Hence, it suffices to prove only when $|z|<1$.